# How to delete the contents of the zip file but not the directory

Tags: java

I am trying to delete the contents of zip file but not the zip directory.I tried `FileUtils.cleanDirectory(deteleOldZip)`, but got an error "abc.zip is not a directory".

Is there any other way to do in a single line?

Comment: Why can't use `new File(deleteOldZip).delete()`?

Comment: Hi, Its returning false.String deleteOldZip = "C://Users//gem5kor//Desktop//MyTask//template_export//JKE_Test_com.bosch.rtc.tmpl.JKE_Bank.15.0.Planning.zip//template";
  System.out.println("here :" + new File(deleteOldZip).delete());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just want an empty zip file

```
String name = file.getAbsolutePath();
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(file)
```

Then create a new empty zip directory with the file path.